# MySQL query to efficiently return combined rows excluding duplicated info

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

So this is likely something simple, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out an efficient way of doing this. I've looked at many other Q&A's, and I've messed with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, sub-queries, etc.

I've tried to super-simplify this example. (for the purpose of the example, there's no DB normalization) Here's a SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/948be7c/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(90) NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NULL,
  `phone` varchar(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `phone`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Bob', 'bob@email.com', NULL),
  ('2', 'Bobby', 'bob@email.com', '1115551111'),
  ('3', 'Robert', 'robert@email.com', '1115551111'),
  ('4', 'Fred', 'fred@email.com', '1115552222'),
  ('5', 'Freddy', 'fred@email.com', '1115553333')
```

If I just run a simple select, I'll get:

[image: basic result]

But I'd like to "de-duplicate" any results that have the same email address or that have the same phone number - because they will be the same people, even if there are multiple ID's for them, and even if their names are spelled different. And then consolidate those results (one of the "distinct" email addresses and one of the "distinct" phone numbers along with one of the names and one of the ID's.)

**So that for the above, I'd end up with something like this:**

[image: desired result]

Any suggestions?

Comment: what determines which id/name to return for duplicates?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate data in the first place? You should normalize your database, so that all the customer information is in a single row in another table, and the `order` table has a foreign key to the `customer` table.

Comment: I've tried multiple variations of DISTINCT and GROUP BY, but I'm not getting what I'm after. (And my actual database is far more complex, so those queries aren't relevant.)

Comment: Which ID / Name really don't matter. Just need to be one of the ones that match the email and phone.

Comment: You have to pick one set of columns to group by. I don't think there's any way to group by a variable set of columns.

Comment: So you can't do "group by email OR phone".

Comment: not with group by.  you need joins

Comment: I know this sample database table isn't normalized. (Most of the actual database is.) But allowing for rapid user entry can result in data with "missing pieces", and I'd like to be able to combine the relevant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do what you want by filtering with a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.id = (
    select o1.id
    from orders o1
    where o1.email = o.email or o1.phone = o.phone
    order by o1.phone is not null desc, o1.email is not null desc, id
    limit 1
)
```

This retains just one row out of those that have the same `phone` or `email`, while giving priority to the row whose `phone` and `email` is not `null`. Ties are broken by picking the lowest `id`.

For your sample data, this returns:

```
id  name    email           phone
2   Bobby   bob@email.com   1115551111
4   Fred    fred@email.com  1115552222
```

Comment: I need to refactor this into my scenario - but it appears to do what I need! I've used it plenty in WHERE clauses, but I wasn't familiar with the ability to include IS NOT NULL in the ORDER BY - I'll have to do some reading on that!

Comment: @BeninCA yes, order by can contain any expression, not just columns.  do try out this approach with a realistic number of records and make sure it performs adequately for your needs

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways your requirements could be interpreted.

One way would be to reframe it as a constraint: only return a record if one of these is true:

- it has a non-null email and phone, and no record exists with the same email and phone and a lower id
- it has a non-null email but null phone, and no record exists with the same email and a non-null phone, and no record exists with the same email and a null phone and a lower id
- it has a non-null phone but null email, and no record exists with the same phone and a non-null email, and no record exists with the same phone and a null email and a lower id

This translates easily into a couple of joins, no group by or distinct required.

Comment: Hmm. I think what you've suggested would accomplish what I'm needing. I hadn't thought of the "lower id" concept.

Comment: When you say constraint - do you mean as part of the ON statement on a JOIN or with a WHERE?